# python data structure suggestion

Tags: python, data-structures

I have some input coming from various sources. Input is in key value pair form. Keys are of type 'a.b.c' form. Keys coming in from different sources can be same and in that case i have to do a set of all values.

Things I need to do with the data structure:

- I should be able to retrieve all the keys and values for a specific source id
- Given a key, I should be able to find out all the values associated with it, irrespective of the source id.

I want one or more space efficient data structures I can use to achieve this. I was originally thinking of keeping 2 maps: one for source id vs keys, and other for key vs values. But here I am losing the source id to value mapping.

Speed/Space requirements:
The speed to get a list of values per key is important; so is the memory required to maintain these data structures. Time taken to build this data structure and source id to key/value retrieval speed isn't vital.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly modify your idea: keep one dictionary associating sources with (key, value) pairs, and another associating keys with sets of values. This should be quick to build/update (adding an entry takes two dict lookups and a list/set insertion), and not require too much memory overhead. Then each of the two lookup operations you want only require a single dictionary hit each.

Note that this only doubles the number of pointers to the actual data; if the values are large, then memory usage will be much less than doubled. If that's an issue, though, and you don't mind making the source id to key-value lookup much slower, then you could store only a dictionary from keys to (source, value) pairs. Then you can get all the values for a given key by

```
vals_for_key = [val for source, val in the_dict[key]]
```

and the key-value pairs from a given source by

```
keyvals_for_source = [(key, val)
                      for key, items in the_dict.iteritems()
                      for src, val in items
                      if src == source]
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work but that seems like a fair increase in memory. Reason why it looks inefficient to me is that we are keeping **almost** same information twice i.e. key/value pair

Comment: @user2121826 See my edit for a more memory-efficient way if that's an issue.

Comment: This seems much better.. let me try this one. Thanks!